# Задача по геометрии с двумя пересекающимися окружностями

Tags: javascript, геометрия, biginteger

Есть две пересекающиеся окружности, известен радиус первой окружности и площадь пересечения окружностей, найти радиус второй окружности. Расстояние между центрами окружностей равно радиусу первой окружности.

[image: две пересекающиеся окружности]

Для меня оказалось площадь пересечения найти не проблема зная оба радиуса окружностей. Но как выразить из этой формулы нахождение радиуса окружности по известной площади пересечения и радиусу другой окружности оказалось непосильной задачей.

Подойдет код на любом языке программирования, но предпочтительнее JS. Надо написать функцию, на входе которой два числа BigInt. Результат вернуть также в формате BigInt, округлив дробное значение до целого числа. Диапазон возможных значений задан диапазоном BigInt. Циклом перебрать все возможные варианты не получится.

Квадратный корень из числа BigInt можно вычислить этой функцией:

```
function sqrt(x) {
  let m = 4n<<0x10000n;
  let y = 0n;
  while (m != 0n) {
    let b = y | m;
    y >>= 1n;
    if (x >= b) {
      x -= b;
      y |= m;
    }
    m >>= 2n;
  }
  return y;
}
```

Comment: Семь тысяч репутация у человека. "площадь пересечения найти не проблема" - *... но я вам ее не отдам*. "но предпочтительнее JS" - еще и код дать?

Comment: @Igor за 500 репы, по-братски :-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не понимаете

Comment: Площадь пересечения двух окружностей считается легко: нужно сложить площади сегментов двух окружностей и вычесть площадь треугольников, образующихся точками центров окружностей и двух точек пересечения окружностей.

Comment: Не "сегментов", а "секторов".

Comment: А может [ЭТО](https://abakbot.ru/online-2/73-ploshhad-peresecheniya-okruzhnostej) поможет, задача не та же, но формулы красивые (там известные радиусы ищем площадь, можно формулы преобразовать)

Answer (score 1):

Для вычисления площади пересечения есть [формула 14 на mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html). Заменив `d` на `R`, получим формулу попроще, но всё равно для решения обратной задачи придётся использовать численные методы, т.к. нельзя получить формулу и выразить радиус `r` через площадь `A`

Пример на Python c простейшим бинарным поиском (зависимость `A` от `r` в данном случае монотонна).

```
from math import acos, sqrt, pi

def findRadius(A, R):
    if A > pi*R*R or A < 0:
        return None
    lo = 0
    hi = 2 * R
    while hi - lo > 0.000001: #задаём точность поиска решения
        r = (lo + hi) / 2
        ar = r*r*acos(0.5*r/R) + R*R*acos(1-(r*r)/(2*R*R))-0.5*r*sqrt(4*R*R-r*r)
        if A < ar:
            hi = r
        else:
            lo = r
    return r


print(findRadius(33, 2))
print(findRadius(3, 2))
print(findRadius(1, 2))
print(findRadius(0, 2))

None
1.5102319717407227
0.835993766784668
9.5367431640625e-07
```

(проверяем [здесь](https://abakbot.ru/online-2/73-ploshhad-peresecheniya-okruzhnostej) - совпадает)